# Split large Software Project on Azure DevOps Repos

Tags: c#, git, azure, devops, clearcase

We are currently in the process of migrating from IBM ClearCase as centralized Version Control to Git / Azure DevOps. It is a large and long grown software project in C# with more than 100 C# projects distributed over about a dozen solutions with some dependencies inbetween, at the moment via Project References.

So far all those solutions were managed with ClearCase in a common folder, however for Git it seems to be best practise to use one solution per repo and handle dependencies cross repo with NuGet Packages.

I wanted to ask for experiences in migrating and splitting such projects, did you come across situations where it was better to include multiple C# solutions in a repo?

How do you manage multiple repositories that belong to one software with one release cycle? We plan on using release branches and I think we have to write a script that branches all repositories belonging to the project or is there a more convenient way, maybe provided by Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written before on [ClearCase migration to Git](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3A6309%20%5Bclearcase%5D%20git%20migration).

In all instances, the scenario was the same:

- don't import the full history, only major labels or UCM baselines
- split VObs per project, each project being one Git repository
- revisit what was versioned in Vobs: some large files/binaries might need to be `.gitignore`'d in the new Git repository.

You can still reference all your Git repository (C# projects) in one parent Git repository, through [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

You can also go the monorepo route: after all, that is what Microsoft is doing with its "[The largest Git repo on the planet](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/the-largest-git-repo-on-the-planet/)".

But in that case, you might need to use [Scalar](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/introducing-scalar/), and sparse checkouts.
See:

- "[Bring your monorepo down to size with sparse-checkout](https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout)"
- "[Make your monorepo feel small with Git’s sparse index](https://github.blog/2021-11-10-make-your-monorepo-feel-small-with-gits-sparse-index/)"